# How to grep a single line with a pattern containing single quotes, pipe and a pattern with a / after?

Tags: grep

i've a file as below

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
'DEF'|filler|'N'|'jane/3'|'text'
```

i want my grep to return the following results

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|john/1|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|mary/2|'text'
```

whereby the conditions are

1. containing the word ABC
2. matching the pattern of either 'Y' or 'N' and after the pipe should contain a forward slash

i'm currently stuck at

**wordY="'Y'|"**

**wordN="'N'|"**

**grep ABC test.txt | grep "$wordY|$wordN"**

which are returning

```
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john1'|'te/xt'    //i do not want this
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
```

how do i add on to the command to return results values with forward slash in the 4th column as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -E "^'ABC'\|[^|]*\|'(Y|N)'\|'[[:alpha:]]+/" input_file
'ABC'|filler|'Y'|'john/1'|'text'
'ABC'|filler|'N'|'mary/2'|'text'
```

Comment: hi, i've edited for a more accurate representation. for the 4th column, it is not literally 'name', just a representation. basically it can be any name, but i want to retrieve names with a / in it

Comment: @UVERtainment Please check edit

Comment: Thank you. 1 more question if i may. would u happen to know how to remove only the / in the name, assuming there are / in the 5th column for the same single line?

Comment: @UVERtainment That sounds like a new question in which case a new question should be asked with relevant samples and expected output. It also sounds like a question either `sed` or `awk` would handle easily.

Comment: @EdMorton I have addressed the issue. Thanks